# Python 3 - Extract content between <td></td>

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = open('C:\folder')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
emails = soup.find_all('td', text = re.compile('@'))

for line in emails:
   print(line)
```

I have the script above that works perfect in Python 2.7 with Beautifulsoup for extracting content between several  in a HTML-file. When I run the same script in Python 3.6.4, however, I get the following results:

```
<td>xxx@xxx.com</td>
<td>xxx@xxx.com</td>
```

I want the content between without the TD stuff...

Why is this happening in Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = open('C:\folder')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser') #Lade till html.parser
emails = soup.find_all('td', text = re.compile('@'))

for td in emails:
   print(td.get_text())
```

Look close at the two last lines :)